# Conditional component error on provided types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I'm trying to build a component to render a form element. This component is basically a conditional rendering.  I tried to build a component that can grow in time with more and more form element.

I've made a simple example of what is my problem. In this example my react component **FormElement** can render a input or an textArea depending on the props **Formtype** that you pass. When the component renders it will trigger the function **RenderCorrectFormElement** which will choose the correct component to display.

My problem is more a typing problem. Input and textArea a normally custom element its why I had

`DetailedHTMLProps<TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>,HTMLTextAreaElement>`

but now when I do {...props} in the input I've got a type error because it doesn't recognize the textArea props.

I'm looking for help to properly type this component if possible scalable possibilities.
thank for your help

```ts
import {
  DetailedHTMLProps,
  InputHTMLAttributes,
  TextareaHTMLAttributes,
} from "react";
import { DeepMap, FieldError, FieldValues } from "react-hook-form";

type FormElementType<
  T extends FieldValues,
  R extends inputType | TextAreaType
> = {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  errors: Partial<DeepMap<T, FieldError>>;
  Formtype: "input" | "textArea";
} & Omit<R, "name" | "id">;

type inputType = {
  name: string;
  size: number;
} & Omit<
  DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>,
  "size"
>;

type TextAreaType = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  label: string;
  className?: string;
} & DetailedHTMLProps<
  TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>,
  HTMLTextAreaElement
>;

function FormElement<
  T extends FieldValues,
  R extends inputType | TextAreaType
>({ name, id, errors, Formtype, ...props }: FormElementType<T, R>) {
  function RenderCorrectFormElement() {
    switch (Formtype) {
      case "input":
        return <input type="text" name={name} id={id} {...props} />;
      case "textArea":
        return <textarea name={name} id={id} {...props} />;
    }
  }
  return <>{RenderCorrectFormElement()} </>;
}
```

**error message**

> Type '{ type: "text"; name: string; id: string; } & Omit<FormElementType<T, R>, "name" | "id" | "errors" | "Formtype">' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes, HTMLInputElement>'.
> Type '{ type: "text"; name: string; id: string; } & Omit<FormElementType<T, R>, "name" | "id" | "errors" | "Formtype">' is not assignable to type 'ClassAttributes'.
> Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
> Type 'FormElementType<T, R>["ref"] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef | undefined'.
> Type 'R["ref"]' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef | undefined'.
> Type 'string | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject | ((instance: HTMLTextAreaElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...> | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef | undefined'.
> Type '(instance: HTMLTextAreaElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef | undefined'.
> Type '(instance: HTMLTextAreaElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
> Type 'HTMLInputElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLTextAreaElement | null'.
> Type 'HTMLInputElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLTextAreaElement': cols, rows, textLength, wrapts(2322)
> (property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.input: DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes, HTMLInputElement>

[image: fff]

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: @Alopwer I've put the error message and where it'a appear

Comment: What if you pass `{...props as unknown as TextAreaType}`?

Comment: it's not the best way though, it'd be better if you find more 'TypeScript' way solution for long-term development

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextAreComponent
            {...(props as unknown as TextAreaProps)}
            className={classNames({ "style.error": hasError })}
            {...(register && register(name, rules))}
            name={name}
            label={""}
            aria-invalid={hasError}
            id={id}
          />
```